# How to Redirect Buddypress Directories To Login Page For Non Logged in Users

Tags: php, functions, multisite

**How to Redirect Buddypress Directories To Login Page For Non Logged in Users?**

I'm also using the Yuzify plugin. It gives a code for it, but it's not working on multisite. ***Can anyone modify this code or provide me with a new code for it?***

```
/**
* Redirect Buddypress Directories To Login Page For Non Logged in Users.
*/
function yzc_redirect_bp_directories_to_login_page() {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( bp_is_groups_directory() || bp_is_members_directory() ) ) {
        
        // Get Buddypress Pages;
        $bp_pages = get_option( 'bp-pages' );
        
        // Get Redirection Url
        $redirect_url = youzify_get_login_page_url();
        
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yzc_redirect_bp_directories_to_login_page' );
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is `youzify_get_login_page_url`? Have you raised this with Yuzify's support?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
* Redirect Buddypress Directories To Login Page For Non Logged in Users.
*/
function yzc_redirect_bp_directories_to_login_page() {
   if (is_main_site()) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && (is_page( 'members' )|| is_page( 'groups' )  || bp_is_group() || bp_is_user()  ) ) { 
         // Get Redirection Url
         if ( function_exists( 'youzify_get_login_page_url' )) {
            $redirect_url = youzify_get_login_page_url();
        }
        else {
            $redirect_url=wp_login_url( get_permalink() );
        }
        
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit(); 
    }
  }
} 

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'yzc_redirect_bp_directories_to_login_page' );
```

Comment: Please also explain why your code should work, instead of just giving the CODE as an answer. Best Regards.